# django rest framework , order_by a JSON from serializers.py file

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with the django rest framework and I want make a order by to my json 
How I can  make a order_by with django rest framework  from  the serializers.py file
I have this in serializers.py

```
class EstablecimientoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Establecimiento
        depth = 1
        fields =   ('nombre','ciudad',)
    order_by = (
        ('nombre',)
    )
```

I have this order_by but  this does nothing with the JSON

What is the correct way to do this order by in the JSON from serializers.py?

I have in  views.py

```
class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.order_by('nombre')
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('categoria','categoria__titulo',)
```

Then the order_by not work  because I have this filter,
How I can do to make the filter work well with order_by?

Answer (score 10):

There's an easy way, just override it explicitly by add a ordering line:

```
class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
    ordering = ('nombre',) #add this line
    filter_fields = ('categoria','categoria__titulo',)
```

Comment: What if you want a nested field to be ordered?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the serializer for ordering. You need to use `queryset` attribute in your view like so:

```
class EstablecimientoListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.order_by('nombre')
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        qs = super(EstablecimientoListView, self).filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
        qs = qs.order_by('nombre')
        return qs
```

Comment: This is fine, but as I have a filter on the view this order_by not work.
    class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

        queryset = Establecimiento.objects.order_by('nombre')
        serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
        filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
        filter_fields =   ('categoria','categoria__titulo',)

Comment: @user3236034 I've updated my post, seems like the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I failed to do what I wanted